# Why doesn't my hopper put drops into a chest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built a Mob XP farm with a hopper and chest for drops, but for some reason the hopper doesn't put the items into the chest. Drops just seem to sit in the hoppers inventory.

Has anyone had similar issues?

Comment: Is the hopper pointing to the chest?

Comment: a screenshot of the hopper and chest would help

Comment: I don't see why the question is unclear, it's in the title.

Comment: @LTPro it's more like he didn't say how he oriented the hopper (which is the answer here most likely)

Comment: @LTPro This should remain closed until a screenshot is posted.  Answers can cover all possible problems, but we want to specifically cover the asker's problem.

Comment: Ok I understand, forgive me for my ignorance.

Answer (score 14):

The hopper is probably not attached to the chest. You have to right-click the chest with the hopper in your hand to place the hopper and connect it to the chest.

You can right-click the hopper onto the chest by crouching while you right-click. Since right-clicking a chest normally *opens* the chest and the crouch-right-click trick is new, people don't try it, and they get non-functioning, unconnected hoppers sitting beside chests.